# TFS Release gates do not fire

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS Release gates to call severall api's before i deploy.
Usually this works great. But sometimes the gates don't fire at all and the api is never called.

I set the timeout on 5 minutes.. so after 5 minutes it should try again.... But that sheduled is then messed up. sometimes it retries after 5 minutes (as it is supposed to) but sometimes it takes 11 or 12 minutes.....

It looks like the requests are queued somewhere... but i really gave no idea.
Anybody knows this behaviour  ?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

**The Delay before evaluation** is a time delay at the beginning of the gate evaluation process that allows the gates to initialize, stabilize, and begin providing accurate results for the current deployment

[image]

*Gate* actually is a sever task which is currently **run on server**.  Some examples could prove

- On-premise - Any on-premise/behind the firewall resources are
  inaccessible
- Env Variables - some of the environment variables are not accessible
  (they are not yet initialized at the time of gate check)

It's run by release service account just as other tasks in release pipeline.

Besides, Delay before evaluation is meant to be the time samples from the gates might be **unreliable**. It's an acceptable phenomena. Sometimes it may need more time than your configuration to do the check.

[image]

Source Link: [Release approvals and gates overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I agree with you. But i thought that the gate checks are agentless. So I am wondering where this api call is executed and by who. Is it an agent, is it the server itself, and why is it waiting so long to start. Fiddler will be of no use because i can see that after 20 minutes my API is hit with the first call, so there is no network traffic. Also i know the call has not started yet because otherwise i would get a timeout.

Comment: @Well0549 Thanks for your quick response. If this could not be tracked through fiddler, then it should not be agent based. After go through official related links and create some test.  Verified, Gate actually is a sever task which is currently run on server. It's run by release service account just as other tasks in release pipeline. Also have updated my reply. Please kindly check. Besides, Delay before evaluation is meant to be the time samples from the gates might be **unreliable**. It's an acceptable phenomena.